# Sending complete JSON with asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I want to send this Json to a server :

```
{
    "id":123,
    "person": {"name":"john", "surname":"john"},
    "qualities": ["gentle", "handsome"],
    "friends": [{"name":"sam", "surname":"gamgee"}, {"name":"donald", "surname":"trump"}]
}
```

So a rather complete json with all possible cases (normal field, json field, list field and json list field).

I want to post this kind of objects on my asp.net mvc server. I post it with the HTTP Header "Content: application/json" and I don't want to change.

I tried many things but I always have an issue at the end, especially when I have a json list field.
Why this kind of thing does not work ?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendJson(dynamic json) {
    json.friends[0].name --> error
}
```

when I send `{"json": {#json above#} }`.

Comment: can you try json.json.friends[0].name ? Curious if its just an issue with how your passing the json as an object in another json.

Comment: Not working either. Actually not wrapping it around a "json" field does not work because asp.net seems to directly parse the json sent and so the parameters are the json fields.

Comment: json.json.friends[0].name - works, any trouble with that?

Comment: Why are you using `dynamic` instead of creating a model class for the type you're trying to post?

Answer (score 0):

Use concrete types.

```
public class Person {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }
}

public class Friend {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string surname { get; set; }
}

public class DataModel {
    public int id { get; set; }
    public Person person { get; set; }
    public IList<string> qualities { get; set; }
    public IList<Friend> friends { get; set; }
}
```

Update controller to expect strong type.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SendJson([FromBody] DataModel model) {
    var name = model.friends[0].name;
}
```

And finally when sending, send the first snippet as is

```
{
    "id":123,
    "person": {"name":"john", "surname":"john"},
    "qualities": ["gentle", "handsome"],
    "friends": [{"name":"sam", "surname":"gamgee"}, {"name":"donald", "surname":"trump"}]
}
```

not wrapped in another object. otherwise you would need an additional object

```
public class RootObject {
    public DataModel json { get; set; }
}
```

to match this `{"json": {#json above#} }`

Comment: I'm pretty sure it works. But you definitely understand i can't afford to create hundreds of models like that for all my requests...

Comment: @fazega In the end it will benefit you. It's quicker to create hundreds of models then to have to solve an issue for each one of them. You can use a tool like automapper to map the fields, though I never used it.

Answer (score 0):

Worked fine.. screenshot contains postman & .net watch window..

[image]

Comment: fazega sends {"json": {#json above#} } not {#json above#}

Comment: json.json.friends[0].name - works, any trouble with that?

Comment: What headers do you use ?

Comment: Content-Type, application/json

Answer (score 0):

MVC can't do resolve dynamic parameters by itself, you have to create your own ModelBinder to catch the input stream of data and create the dynamic object yourself.

See the method [here](https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/payloads-as-dynamic-objects-in-asp-net-mvc).

Comment: It's not at all clear what you mean by "MVC can't do that by now". We shouldn't have to rely on a link to understand what you mean. Your answer should stand on its own merit, links should be used to supplement your question. They should not be crucial for understanding it.

Comment: Better now ? I didn't develop because it answers my question : it's not possible to do what I want automatically, you have to create your own binders ...

Comment: A little bit. I fixed up your grammar: MVC is not a masculine or feminine object, and thus not a "he" or "she", but an "it". Also, your should be clear what you mean by "that". I have edited your answer to correct these issues.